# How do I select an object by a sub-property

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, object, join

i've got a List of objects, lets call them Product, which each of them contains a bunch of properties and also a List of Version (which are also objects).
Version also has a bunch of properties and does contain a List of Customer (which again are objects).
Customer again has properties, one of them is its ID (=Guid).

What i try to do is to make a List of Product, selected by a certain ID of its Product.VersionList.Version.ID.

I would prefere a join query, but every efficient way is welcome. I tried so far this, but because i have only a single ID to compare with, i don't know how to construct the join.

```
lp = List<Entity.Product>;
g = GetGuid();

var query = from product in Entity.ProductCollection
            join g in g
            on product.Version.Where(x => x.id == g)
            select product;

lp.AddRange(query);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this .... May be you wants more deep digging on it..

```
var query = from Product product in pc
            from varsion in product.Version
            let v= varsion as Entity.Version
            where  v.id == g
            select product;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you mean:

```
var query = from product in Entity.ProductCollection
            where product.Version.Any(x => x.id == g)
            select product;
```

i.e. select all the products that have a version where the id matches the guid you were thinking of.

Note that joining to the versions would cause product duplication if any product has multiple matching versions.

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = Entity.ProductCollection.Where(p => p.Version.Any(v => v.Id == g));
```

You can use [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) rather than having to do a self join.